# Exporting canvas to image is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, html5-canvas, export

I tried to export a canvas as a png image. I used the below code to do this.

```
function onExport() {
        var canvas = $("#container_canvas")[0]; //id of the canvas 
        var dt = canvas.toDataURL();
        this.href = dt; 
    }
```

This works in all other browsers except IE. No action takes place. I use IE 10 version.
Help me to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: what is this $("#container_canvas")[0] ?? you have already used a jQuery selector which will return you the id then [0] for what ..please try to debug and get know what "$("#container_canvas")[0]" is returning ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete example of creating an html img element from the canvas.

It works fine in IE10.

If the user desires, they can right-click-save-as the new img.

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");


ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.fillRect(50,50,150,55);
ctx.strokeRect(50,50,150,55);
ctx.fillStyle='white';
ctx.font='14px verdana';
ctx.fillText('Click the canvas',55,65);
ctx.fillText('to save it as',55,80);
ctx.fillText('a new image',55,95);


canvas.addEventListener("click",function(){
  var img=new Image();
  img.onload=function(){
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
  img.src=canvas.toDataURL();
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
img{border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<h4>Click the canvas. The new blue element is an img</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```